# Dynamically changing tableView cell height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Is there any method to increase or decrease the cell's height in a table view depending on text of a label in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get the height of the label (Dynamically) depending on the length of your text:

```
// Set space for content height
let frameForPostContentLabel = NSString(string:  content).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 120), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)], context: nil)
```

and then you can set the height of the tableview:

```
cell.postContentLabelHeight.constant = frameForPostContentLabel.height
```